# search query using and operator not working in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
     OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandText = "select  customer_id,customer_name,customer_mobile1,customer_address from tb_customer where ( (customer_mobile1 = ? ) && (customer_name = ? ))";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_mobile1", txt_no.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_name", txt_name.Text);


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
```

this is my code that i have written for searching...if both the fields are filled only then it should return result...but it is giving error in syntax...can anyone please help me??

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** You have used `&&` for combining the two conditions.
**Solution :** You should use `AND` instead of `&&`

Try This:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select  customer_id,customer_name,customer_mobile1,customer_address from tb_customer where ( (customer_mobile1 = ? ) AND (customer_name = ? ))";
```

Answer (score 0):

the command text is what will be run in the db. hence it is SQL not C#. And in SQL is `and` not `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Plus, if you're not doing so already, be sure to clean the value in the text boxes.

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_mobile1", txt_no.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_name", txt_name.Text);
```

This will potentially result into sql injection hacks. So make sure to filter out and clean the data any users enter. Everywhere. Always.